# VBA For loop keeps going even though the bounds are met

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

So I have a code running with something like this:

```
maxRow = 5

For numRow=1 to maxRow

    If Range("A" & numRow).Value = 0 Then

        Rows(numRow).Select

        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        numRow = numRow - 1 

        maxRow = maxRow - 1 

    End If

Next numRow
```

and I have

> A1 to A5 = 4 0 3 1 9 (respectively)

yet for some reason the loop keeps going

Anyone please help me so I end up with A1=4, A2=3, A3=1 and A4=9 without continuous looping.

Comment: `numRow = numRow - 1` means it never goes past 1. Also, when deleting rows, loop backwards.

Comment: @findwindow: not quite, since `numRow = numRow - 1` happens only `If Range("A" & numRow).Value = 0` while `numRow` gets updated at each `For numRow=1 to maxRow` iteration. the acual issue is that in a `For counter=iniCounter to endCounter` the `endCounter` value stays with its initial value throughout the entire loop

Comment: @user3598756 good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's better to go **backwards**:

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub ytrewq()
maxRow = 5

For numRow = maxRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("A" & numRow).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(numRow).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next numRow
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

***NOTE:***

Nothing gets decremented.
The `Select` is not necessary:

```
Sub ytrewq()
maxRow = 5

For numRow = maxRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("A" & numRow).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(numRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next numRow
End Sub
```

will work just as well.

Comment: mmm problem is I simplified this problem because deleting the row is part of a much larger for loop I have going with starts at row 2 and goes to row 10000 or so... I was hoping there was an easy way to fix it without changing the structure of the for loop.

Comment: @MauroAugusto  The code I posted is a pretty standard way of handling this need......................if we can see more of your code, we may be able to help you adapt it.

Comment: @MauroAugusto, my guess is that you'll be better off breaking out those multiple tasks into separate loops/procedures. At any rate, you've got the correct answer here to the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is because in a `For - Next` loop you determine the number of iterations when you first enter the loop, no matter if during the loop itself you're updating a variable involved in its end condition.

when you don't know in advance how many times to run the statements in the loop,  like in your case, then use a `Do While - Loop` loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim maxRow As Long, numRow As Long

maxRow = 5
numRow = 1
Do While numRow <= maxRow

    If Range("A" & numRow).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(numRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        maxRow = maxRow - 1
    Else
        numRow = numRow + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @MauroAugusto: did you get through it?